# Remotely sensed estimate of mangrove area for all of the Galapagos Islands

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am looking for a remotely sensed estimate of mangrove area (derived from an RS image) for all of the Galapagos Islands.

Not:

Hamilton SE, Casey D (2016) Creation of a high spatio-temporal resolution global database of continuous mangrove forest cover for the 21st century (CGMFC-21). Global Ecology and Biogeography 25 (6):729-738. [doi:10.1111/geb.12449](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/geb.12449/abstract)

nor

Giri C, Ochieng E, Tieszen LL, Zhu Z, Singh A, Loveland T, Masek J, Duke N (2011) Status and Distribution of Mangrove Forests of the World Using Earth Observation Satellite Data. Global Ecology and Biogeography 20 (1):154-159. [doi:10.1111/j.1466-8238.2010.00584.x](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1466-8238.2010.00584.x/abstract)

These two are global estimates that contain the Galapagos Islands. I am looking for an analysis particularly designed for the Galapagos.